# Inserting and searching for multiple keywords

Tags: php, mysql

I am planning designing a PHP MySQL database for a local museum's photo gallery.

One thing that terrifies me now is how to implement saving multiple keywords for a single image for items where more than one technic or material was used to design them, e.g. 
PAINTING TECHNICS:(liner, wiping, scumbling), MATERIAL USED: (oil, canvas,).

Ideally, I would have to use the select option lists to save them for each record. But if I want to save two or more of the words from the same list, I cant.

Do you have any suggestions I might consider?

joseph

Comment: MySQL supports [full-text search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to implement a one-to-many relationship between your image table and your keyword table. **One** image can have **many** keywords. Each row in your keyword table will need to reference a row in the image table through a foreign key. For example:

```
images

id | asset
---------------
1  | image1.png 
2  | image2.png

keywords

id | image_id | keyword   | category
-----------------------------------------------
1  | 1        | liner     | painting techniques
2  | 1        | wiping    | painting techniques
3  | 1        | scumbling | painting techniques
3  | 2        | oil       | material used
```

Or something along those lines. This is how you allow one row (an image) to be associated with many rows (keywords) in a different table.

For each keyword submitted, you would add another row to the keywords table, making sure to reference the associated image.

Comment: I guess this is the best option +1 for that

Comment: Would I be able to add them from the same select option box?

Comment: Are your keywords predefined, or can a user create new keywords? If they are predefined, you could use a <select multiple> tag to allow them to select multiple. Another option would be to use checkboxes -- show all of the possible keywords for an image, and let the user check which ones they want to associate with the image. If the keywords are not predefined, then you could use a textfield and have the user enter in a comma separated list of the keywords that you could parse.